# Python. Синтаксикация кода с if, elif

Tags: python

проблем две. Первая я не могу написать код с выводом пользователей новых и занятых:

```
current_users = ['james', 'soer', 'fergison', 'daria', 'geradot']
new_users = ['ben', 'adam','james', 'michail', 'linda']
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user not in current_users:
        print(f"Successful registration {new_user}")
    elif new_user in current_users:
        print(f"Sorry but your name {new_user} is close.")
print("\nWellcome!")
```

Пишет Python проблема в строке 6, неправильный отступ, но если его делать то алгоритм не работает.

Вторая проблема я не понимаю как Python допускает вывод имен если (в строке 5)  new_user не может быть выписана полностью из-за имени  'james', но он все-равно выводит и не допускает имя 'james'. В общем как работает Python и почему в 4 и 6 строке он выборочно выписывает списки ведь была дана команда if и elif.

Answer (score 0):

у вас перед `if` находится `\t`, а под `elif` четыре пробела. Замените `\t` на четыре пробела

```
current_users = ['james', 'soer', 'fergison', 'daria', 'geradot']
new_users = ['ben', 'adam','james', 'michail', 'linda']
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user not in current_users:
        print(f"Successful registration {new_user}")
    elif new_user in current_users:
        print(f"Sorry but your name {new_user} is close.")
print("\nWellcome!")
```

Comment: А как заметить \t на пробелы?